# AngularJS compare objects of scope outside ng-repeat

Tags: php, angularjs, api

Below code of `$scope.Deelnemers`. 
Example: I have two Users / Deelnemers ID 1 and 2 via API from Mysql-db.

App.js

```
getDeelnemers(){

    $http({
        method: 'POST',
        url: 'api.php?users=users',
        data: {}
    }).then(function successCallback(response) {
        $scope.Deelnemers = response.data;
        console.log('Deelnemers: ',$scope.Deelnemers);
    }, function errorCallback(response) {
        alert('Fout met ophalen sponsors!');
    });
}; 

<div class="row" ng-repeat="Deelnemer in Deelnemers">

        <div class="col-md-1">
            <input name="id" class="form-control input-sm" value="{{Deelnemer.deelnemer_id}}" type="text" disabled>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <input name="names" class="form-control input-sm" value="{{Deelnemer.naam}}" type="text" disabled>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-1">
            <input name="groupsnr" class="form-control" ng-model="Deelnemer.groupnr" ng-change="saveAssingDeelnemerGroupnr(Deelnemer.groupnr,Deelnemer.deelnemer_id)"></input>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3" ng-init="getSponsorName(Deelnemer.sponsor)">
            {{ SponsorName }}
        </div>
</div>
```

I would like to show the Sponsorname with a getter getSponsorName(Deelnemer.sponsor).

For User ID 1, Deelnemer.sponsor = 987 and for User ID 2, Deelnemer.sponsor = 789

```
$scope.getSponsorName = function(SponsorId) {   
    if(SponsorId == 987) {
        $scope.SponsorName = "Foo";
    }
    if(SponsorId == 789) {
        $scope.SponsorName = "Bar";             
    }

}
```

Output of {{ SponsorName }} is for both users "Bar" while Deelnemer.sponsor for both is different?

I guess it's something simple what I'm doing wrong but I don't see/know it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting the same value because you are using the same model for all rows,Try the following

html

```
  <div class="col-md-3" ng-init="getSponsorName(Deelnemer)">
        {{ Deelnemer.SponsorName }}
  </div>
```

js

```
$scope.getSponsorName = function(Deelnemer) {   
    if(Deelnemer.SponsorId == 987) {
        Deelnemer.SponsorName = "Foo";
    }
    if(Deelnemer.SponsorId == 789) {
        Deelnemer.SponsorName = "Bar";             
    }
}
```